# Callbacks without concurrency?

Tags: event-programming, asynchronous-programming, callbacks

To sync on the terms I will first give my perspective on what a callback function in the simplest possible terms:

> A callback function is a function that is executed as a response to a  certain event that can happen at arbitrary time.

The `event that can happen at arbitrary time.` implies that some external source is producing the event which implies that some executions has to be concurrent.

Is there a meaning behind callback function that means something in a non concurrent environment?

Comment: What do you mean by "is there a meaning?"  Also, can you be more clear about what you mean by "concurrency?"  Do you mean "code running on multiple threads," or "code running on different machines?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey If it's sensible. For example as one doesn't use/work with/talk about mutexes in single threaded programs.

Comment: When you say "non-concurrent environment," do you mean that the callback event *does not* happen at some arbitrary time, i.e. as a result of some external event?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes

Comment: How, then, does the callback get executed?

Comment: @RobertHarvey By something that happened in another thread.

Comment: I consider that a *concurrent* environment.  A callback that is called from another thread is conceptually no different from a callback that is executed from some other source, like a returning AJAX request.

Comment: @ Sorry, misunderstood you. I don't know what would fire the event's which is why the callback in that environment doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: By "that environment" do you mean "from another thread?"  The other thread registers itself with the callback event.  When the thread has finished its work, it fires the event which executes the callback method.

Comment: I don't know what would fire the event's which is why the callback in non-concurrent environment doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: I just want to be clear... Do you consider two threads running at the same time to be a "non-concurrent environment?"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38696/discussion-between-robert-harvey-and-alan).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if your "external" source is really other code run in a single threaded program (not at all uncommon, by the way), then the callback happens when the other code chooses to use it, such as visiting something.

FWIW, Wikipedia says [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)):

> In computer programming, a callback is a piece of executable code that is passed as an argument to other code, which is expected to call back (execute) the argument at some convenient time. The invocation may be immediate as in a synchronous callback, or it might happen at a later time as in an asynchronous callback. In all cases, the intention is to specify a function or subroutine as an entity that is, depending on the language, more or less similar to a variable.

I would say that if you use the term callback, without saying synchronous or asynchronous, I would infer a synchronous callback, because of historical perspective and the over-weighted history of single threaded programming.

---

Even an asynchronous callback does not necessarily imply multi-threading or concurrency; Wikipedia says that async and deferred callbacks simply execute later, not necessarily concurrently.

I would say that when you have concurrency or multi-threading you should probably use the term task over (async) callback.

Comment: Whether the code calling the callback is single-threaded or not seems largely irrelevant, unless you're talking about the same thread that invoked the code that will eventually call the callback.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I guess I'm saying that when someone says callback, I think of a single thread in an application or library.  If I wrote a callback, I wouldn't automatically make it thread safe.  If I was making it thread safe, I'd probably make a Task rather than a callback.

Comment: What else is an external source?

Comment: @Alan, I would say off cpu events, that are usually signaled via hardware interrupts, such as I/O events, mouse events, keyboard, etc...  (In the browser, mouse & key event handled in the one javascript thread, but in an other applications, you can have true asynchronous handlers for these.  Even older UNIX systems that had only one thread per process would suspend the current thread at an arbitrary position in order to run an application-level I/O handler, which leaves you with similar class of problems as in multi-threading!)

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not assume concurrency.  In fact, in JavaScript, there is no concurrency.  At a very high level, the way systems that use events in a single threaded system might look roughly like this:

```
while forever:
      if there are conditions that produce events
           add events to the event queue

      if there are events in the event queue
           take highest priority event off of event queue
           call callback for event
      otherwise
           wait some very short time period
```

Comment: I would say that it is more like a "simulated concurrency," as it allows you to reorder operations so that you can go do some work while you wait for something else to happen (without invoking new threads).  Regardless, the event that you're waiting for is clearly coming from some independent source (i.e. an AJAX call to some other server), otherwise the queue event/callback mechanism amounts to a very elaborate subroutine call/return.

Comment: Often, though, that concurrency is happening at a very low level.  For instance, if the condition is the results of a network call at the socket level, then the first `if` condition in the above while loop is just a call to [select](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(Unix)).  All the concurrency is happening at the OS level.

Comment: The result of a network call at the socket level is an external event.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It does not simulate concurrency. It's a purely cooperative scheduling for tasks of finite duration. What it does provide though is asynchronous execution - which neither implies parallelism nor concurrency. Mind the difference between cooperative and preemptive scheduling, only the second one suffices when talking about concurrency.

Comment: @Ext3h: It doesn't sound like you understood my comment.  Note the scare quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The definition you give on the yellow background is meaningless and does not convey the meaning of a callback at all. A callback is just what the word implies, it calls back (to the caller/client/initiator). And its purpose is to allow the caller/client/initiator to respond to events that happen before the function it called has finished.

A practical use is the enumeration of items. Say you have a function ReadFile() which steps through a file and every time it encounters something interesting that needs to be processed, it reports that to its caller, by calling the callback function that was passed to it. It has nothing to do with threading, in fact, callbacks are typically used to avoid threading.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of any function or method using callbacks should describe how the callback will be used (unless it is obvious).

For synchronous methods a callback is often executed while the method itself is still running, as part of the execution of the method.

For asynchronous methods that return immediately, the callback will often be called long after the method has returned, and it should be documented whether it will be executed on a background thread, on some specific thread, or on the main thread of the application.

Comment: `For synchronous methods a callback is often executed while the method itself is still running, as part of the execution of the method. `
And the same could be achieved with just having the callback code in the synchronous method and avoid the `callback notion` in this context?
It's just executing a function in a function in a sequential order just that the inner (callback) function has been passed as an argument?